# Annotating User objects with filtered Groups

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize user data in Django Rest Framework and I wish to only return selected groups that a user is a member of. Based off if the group name ends with _certified.

I've looked at F expressions, and even Q objects but I can't seem to find an easy way to do this or if it's even possible.

**NB. I'm using the built-in `User` and `Group` models.**

My expected result is

```
{
    "User": {
        ...
        "Groups": ['role1_certified', 'role2_certified' ...] 
    }
}
```

`Groups` should only contain groups that end in `_certified`

Comment: What does your model look like? Are you using an ArrayField or a (foreign key) relationship?

Comment: I'm using the standard django `User` and `Group` models. So `User` has a m2m relationship to `Group`

Comment: You can use `prefetch_related` with `Prefetch` object to filter with `__endwith`, but it return record per m2m connection. If you need to annotate - for PostgreSQL you can use [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg). For others - [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Comment: @YahorTsyplakou could you elaborate maybe with a quick example? I had the issue of a record for each m2m connection when I tried Subquery previously. and ArrayAgg returns AttributeError: can't set attribute.

Comment: @NeilHickman `User.objects.annotate(groups_names=ArrayAgg('groups__name',  filter=Q(groups__name__endwith='_certified')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Yahor's comment the solution I have come to is as follows.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import Q

user = User.objects.annotate(certified_groups=ArrayAgg(
    'groups__name', filter=Q(groups__name__endswith='_certified')))
```